# Random triplet number generator

Tags: random, numbers, triplet

I would like to create code for a random number generator for predetermined sets of triplets (200 sets in total to randomize).  I would like the sets of triplets to form a set of six numbers and the set of triplets to remain unique.

example triplets A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9, 10 11 12, 13 14 15]; etc

I would like resulting triplet to retain their original sequence

1 2 3 + 4 5 6, 1 2 3 + 7 8 9, 1 2 3 + 10 11 12, 1 2 3 + 13 14 15

I am not a coder, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to specify a programming language, otherwise you won't get any actual answers. SO is a place to discuss specific program implementation problems, not algorithms or conceptual problems.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pick three triplets, keeping them in order.  So your first triplet cannot be too close to the end -- there have to be at least two more triplets after it.  Similarly, the second triplet you pick needs at least one unpicked triplet after it.

I assume that you have your triplets in an array or similar, numbered 0 to 199.

1. Pick a random number `A` in the range 0 to 197.  That is the index of your first triplet.
2. Pick a second random number `B` in the range (A + 1) to 198.  That is the index of your second triplet.
3. Pick a third random number `C` in the range (B + 1) to 199.  That is the index of your third triplet.

The range of random numbers you pick from is affected by the numbers you have previously picked and the number of picks remaining.